# objective-c use SBjson read file.json in project but NSArray return null

Tags: json, null, nsarray, internal, sbjson

th.json

```
{"lessons":[{"id":"38","fach":"D"},{"id":"39","fach":"M"}]}
```

ViewController.m

```
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]];
NSString *JsonData = [bundle pathForResource:@"th" ofType:@"json"];

SBJsonParser *parser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init] ;

NSDictionary *jsonObject = [parser objectWithString:JsonData error:NULL];

NSArray *list = [jsonObject objectForKey:@"lessons"];

NSLog(@"%@", list);
```

Output NSLog list return

```
(null)
```

my apps use json file internal my project. 
and "th.json" in my project folder.
but NSArray *list can't display data in Json file.

Answer (score 1):

You need to give the *content* of the file to the SBJsonParser. Your code just gives the *path* to the file to the parser. Try this instead:

```
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]];
NSString *path = [bundle pathForResource:@"th" ofType:@"json"];
NSLog(@"Path: %@", path);

NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
NSLog(@"Data: %@", jsonData);

SBJsonParser *parser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init] ;

NSDictionary *jsonObject = [parser objectWithData:jsonData];
NSLog(@"%@", jsonObject);

NSArray *list = [jsonObject objectForKey:@"lessons"];
NSLog(@"%@", list);
```

Comment: Why build error: No visible @interface for 'SBJson4Parser' declares the selector 'objectWithData:'

Comment: SBJson4Parser is from SBJson version 4 and up, SBJsonParser (which is used in this example) is in SBJson versions *less than* 4. This is a MAJOR VERSION CHANGE because the API changed significantly. Therefore EVERYTHING was renamed so you can use both version 3 and 4 in the same application.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (NSDictionary *dataDict in myitems) {
        NSString *itemName = [dataDict objectForKey:@"itemName"];
        NSLog(@"itemName = %@",itemName);
    }
```

insert String make it work.